# Function parameter or local variable

Tags: c

Let's say I have a loop which repeats millions of times. Inside of this loop I have a function call.

Inside of this function I need to operate on some temporary variable created at the very beginning. Now, which one is better:

a) Create temporary variable at the beginning of the code, initialize it at the beginning of the loop, and pass it as function parameter
b) Create just local temporary variable at the beginning of the called function?

Is this answerable question? I'd like to know which point is considered better practice, or which one is faster.

Comment: Whichever results in cleaner code is better practice -- in this case, declaring the variable inside of the function.  If you are worried about which is faster, then benchmark.

Comment: So what you're asking is: creating the variable in the function versus passing it as a parameter ? Should be pretty comparable.

Comment: Create the local var.  Minimize scope whenever possible.  Speed of both should be identical or even better with the local var (depending on if it is "large" or "dynamic".

Comment: depends on the your design. since you mention **temporary variable at the begining of the code** which i assume is global(file scope),which may indicate design weakness.

Comment: What Michael Dorgan said.  There won't be a bit of performance difference.

Comment: @Koushik I rather meant the beginning of main().

Comment: @Koushik, no he meant creating a local once before the original loop.  But he is calling the another function and that local is just going to created each time the stack frame is created anyway so there is really no cost.

Comment: so in either case your talking about a stack variable.so it really doesnt matter

Comment: Thanks, and just out of curiosity - what if I have a couple of these function calls, and I could - 1. create local variable in each function, or 2 - create one variable and pass this one to all functions as parameter. Same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's throw up some possible definitions for `some_function()`, the function you will be calling from your loop.

```
// Method 1
void some_function() {
    int temporary;

    // Use temporary
}

// Method 2
void some_function(int temporary) {
    // Use temporary
}

// Method 3
void some_function(int *temporary) {
    // Use *temporary
}
```

Method 1 is likely to be the most readable out of these options, and so it's the one I would prefer unless you have a *really* good reason to do something else.  It is also likely to be faster than either of the others, *unless* your compiler is inlining the function call.  If it is, then all three are likely to perform exactly the same (method 3 might still be slower if the compiler isn't able to optimize away the pointer dereferences).

If the compiler is not inlining, then method 2 is likely to be slower than method 1.  This is because, in terms of stack-allocated memory, they are the same -- function arguments are going to be stored on the stack the same way locals are.  The only difference between a function argument and a local in this context is that the function argument can be given a value by the caller.  This step of transferring the value from the caller to the function is (theoretically) going to slow down the invocation.

Method 3 is almost certainly going to be slower, since accesses to the temporary memory will include a level of indirection.  Dereferencing a pointer is not a cheap operation compared to accessing a local.

Of course, if performance is absolutely critical then you should benchmark these approaches.  I suspect that method 1 will turn out to be the fastest (or at least no slower than the others) and additionally seems more readable to me.

Comment: The only thing to mention is stack vs heap var and possible fragmentation if said var is "big".

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is not needed outside the function, then it should be inside the function. This allows the compiler to do the best job of optimising the code, as well as making the code most readable and easy to use (this applies generally, "declare variables with the smallest possible scope", although for small functions, declaring a handful of variables at the top of the function each time is the best option).

From a performance perspective, passing a variable to a function is either equivalent, or worse than having a local variable. [And of course, the compiler may inline everything and you end up with exactly the same code in both cases, but that's dependent on the compiler and the code you have].

As others have mentioned, passing a pointer to a local variable will incur a "penalty" for accessing the pointer to get the value. It may not make a huge difference, but it almost certainly makes some difference. This should definitely be the last resort. [Note that if the variable is LARGE, the overhead of passing a copy to the function may still be worse than the overhead of a pointer. But if we assume it's a simple type like `int` or `float`, then a pointer has noticeable overhead].

Any time there is a question on performance, you DEFINITELY should benchmark YOUR code. Asking someone else on the internet may be worthwhile if there is a choice between algorithms for sorting or something like that, but if it's a case of "is it better to do this or that" in some more subtle differences, then the differences are often small and what your particular compiler does will have much more influence than "which is theoretically better".

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between these two approaches *if* you are passing the variable as a pointer, rather than a value. The pointer will get pushed onto the call stack and will have to be referenced in order to get/set the value.

Conversely, setting it as a local value, or pass by value, will put the value on the stack. It matters not whether it is a local or pass by value in that case... though there is one possible caveat based on how the variable is handled outside of the function in the case of pass by value... if it is stored in a variable (not passing a literal value) then it has to get fetched from memory and pushed on the stack. If it is set from a literal value inside the function, it is just a literal pushed on the stack and saved a memory cycle.

A third option you omit is the use of a global variable.

On the off chance the value is constant, always, then the best answer use a #define and compile it directly into the code as a literal.